# NLog.Targets.Splunk - Possible to get rid of the "Properties" wrap?

Tags: nlog

In: NLog.Targets.Splunk
https://github.com/AlanBarber/NLog.Targets.Splunk

When use the nlog configuration with:

- includeEventProperties="true"

or if I have:

- includeEventProperties="false" and use:

```
        <contextproperty name="host" layout="${machinename}" />
        <contextproperty name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
        <contextproperty name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
```

I get the logs in the following format (properties wrapped in "Properties"):

```
{"Level":"Info","MessageTemplate":"ApiRequest","RenderedMessage":"ApiRequest","Properties":{"httpMethod":"GET","statusCode":200}, ...}
```

Is it possible to get rid of the Properties-wrap, and have it more flat?

```
{ "Level": "Info",  "httpMethod": "GET", "statusCode":200, ... }
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue for: https://github.com/AlanBarber/NLog.Targets.Splunk

Comment: You can also consider publishing to splunk directly: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Webservice-Target-for-Splunk

Comment: Maybe possible to perform batching with JsonLayout + https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.HTTP